# Reading Multiple File in a directory one by one in Node Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, readfile

I'm trying to give a bunch of files in a folder and it should read each file and return the specified information for the correct unique path" ( It means /resource directory has f1.txt , f2.txt files separately like this /resource/f1.txt. )

The output of single file are :

```
{ url: 'account/43',    
  status: '200',    
  headers: [ 'content-type = application/text' ],    
  body: [ '{ name: XYZ }' ] }
```

The url of each file we are storing as one primary variable to check, As below code works fine for single file in a folder. motive here to read all file one by one and save the output in a variable.

```
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')
const _ = require('lodash')

function parseFile(filePath) {
  let content
  let output = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readFile(filePath, function(err, data) {
    if (err) reject( err )
    content = data.toString().split(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g).map(function(line) {
      return line.trim()
    }).filter(Boolean)
    resolve(processFile(content))
  })
})
  return output
}
if (require.main === module) {
  let p = parseFile( path.join(__dirname, '../resources/FileData1.txt') )
  p.then((results => {
    console.log(results.status)
  }))
}
```

Any suggestion would be appreciable, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you are working on just one file. First, you will need to retrieve all the files and then use your function

Step 1 - Get all the files for the given dir.
Step 2 - Create promise for each file.
Step 3 - Use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) and `then` use the callback which will have all the results.

```
if (require.main === module) {
  let dir = path.join(__dirname, '../resources')
  let files = fs.readdirSync(dir) // gives all the files
  let promises = files.map(file => parseFile(path.join(dir, file))) // gives an array of promises for each file
  Promise.all(promises).then(console.log) // Uses Promise.all and resolves all supplied promises with their results. 
  // WIN
}
```

This will give the result in order of `files`.

> motive here to read all file one by one and save the output in a variable.
>   With the approach above, you are not reading file one by one, but rather exploiting the power of promises and allow them to run concurrently.